# SQL query stored in database and run through Python

Tags: sql, python-3.x

I am trying to write Python code which reads the SQL to be run from vertica, but fails to execute the DML.

For example:

Query is stored in a column in the database

```
"INSERT INTO XYZ_table
(col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1,col2,col3
FROM stg_XYZ_table
WHERE idrank = 1"
```

Code first loads this info into a Dataframe:

```
sql_exec = df[sql]
```

Then it executes this:

```
cur.execute(sql_exec)
```

Expected binary or unicode string, got 0

Comment: Can you add code here please for understand what happen.

Comment: `idrank ` column is it a derived or stored column in your table ? also include datatypes for col1,col2,col3

Comment: i found the issue, the output from DF was series and i had to convert it into a list and then exec(string) and its worked fine. Thanks for your response. Also if you can think of a better way to write or handle this, please share here